# Keras - Trying to concatenate two inputs

Tags: python, keras, tensor

I have two inputs to my model, both of which are tensors (one is an input layer, and the other is a embedding layer). I am using the `concatenate` which is for tensors and not `Concatenate` which is for layers. I have does this before without issue, but I currently am using a different dataset where the inputs have a different shape. What I am trying to do is concatenate an image with an embedding matrix and pass it into a densenet121:

```
-----------
|embedding|
|         |
-----------
|  image  |
-----------
```

Here are their original shapes:

```
Image: (?, 224, 224, 1)
embedding: (?, 200, 224)
```

Clearly they are of different size (one is a square and one is more of a rectangle) and have different number of dims. So I tried to concatenate as follows:

```
merged = Concatenate([text_embedding, squeeze(image_input, axis=-1)], axis=1, name='merged')
```

The reasoning behind the squeeze is because it is of shape (?, 224, 224, 1) and embedding is as shown above. I suspect that It could have to either be 1 of 2 things:

1. The concat axis is wrong
2. The concat function cant operate on these inputs (as they may be layers, must use Concat?)
3. Maybe both shapes must have 4 dims?

I have received the following errors:

**default**:

```
ValueError: Shape must be rank 4 but is rank 3 for 'sequential_11/densenet121/zero_padding2d_21/Pad' (op: 'Pad') with input shapes: [?,424,224], [4,2].
```

**for 1)** I tried setting the concat axis to 2 and got:

```
ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 200, 224, 1), (None, 224, 224, 1)]
```

**for 2)** changed `concat` to `Concat` `TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'axis'`

**for 3)** I tried: `expand_dims(text_embedding, axis=-1)` and got: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'`

Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, found my answer:

```
expandedText = Lambda(lambda x: expand_dims(x, axis=-1))
merged = concatenate([expandedText(text_embedding), image_input], axis=1, name='merged')
```

Apparently you have to turn it into a layer before making the graph as found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44627977/keras-multi-inputs-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-inbound-n).